# Как удалить пустоту между body и footer?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Чтобы футер прижимался к низу, я сделал  `position:relative; top:650px;`
Но после этого остается пустота, на некоторых страничках, как раз на эти 650px...

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```
<html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Созданный рецепт</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  <?php require_once "blocks/header.php"?>
  <?php
$img_name = $_FILES['img_name'];
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'kulinar');
$add = "SELECT * FROM `recipe` WHERE `id`=".$_GET['id'];
$info_recept = $mysql->query($add);
  while ($infor = $info_recept->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<h2>". $infor['name'] .":</h2>";
    echo $infor['img_name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo str_replace (['.' , '!'] , '<br/>', $infor ['description']);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h2> Ингредиенты: </h2>";
    echo str_replace (';' ,'<br/>', $infor ['structure']);
    echo "<br>";
    /*echo  "<button class='redach'> <img src='img/redach.png' width='25' height='25'>
     <a href='redac.php?id=<?= $id?>' </button>";*/
  /*  echo "<p> ".$infor ['description']." </p>";
echo "<img src='img/ ".$infor['img_name'].".jpg'  class='img-thumbnail'>";
echo str_replace (['.' , '!'] , '<br/>', $infor ['description']);
    echo "<p> ".$infor ['structure']." </p>";*/
  }
$mysql -> close();
?>
</div>
<?php require_once "blocks/footer.php"?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Поправил]
[image: Содержимое странички]

Comment: Посмотрел, да, решает мой вопрос но не до конца...
Везде подвал размещается сносно, но на страничке с описанием рецепта чересчур близко находится (я делают сайт - кулинарные рецепты, где пользователи могут размещать свои рецепты)

Comment: Создайте минимальное демо

Comment: @Greg-- Поместил скрин

Comment: Попробуйте так [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/jcydm7wx/4/)

Comment: @MaxWatson Лучше, но все равно не то, чего я добивался..((

Comment: @Nik Так чего не хватает? Не понимаю

Comment: @MaxWatson Мне кажется, что дело в самом файле, где добавляются рецепты...
сейчас буду думать.